# Leaflet OSM Marker Popup Positioning

Tags: popup, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm working a map website using OpenStreetMap, and I'm using image marker rather the default one. The first problem when zooming map in or out, marker's position slightly changing... So I set anchor point using L.point. However, the chain reaction happened also to pop up, which described by this picture :

[image]

Popup covered the marker, and the positioning doesn't seem right. Any suggestion how to tinkering popup's point? Here's my code :

```
var locations = data;

for ( var i=0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    if (locations[i][0] == 'panic') {
        var icon = L.icon({iconUrl:"{{asset('assets/splash4.gif')}}", iconAnchor: new L.Point(36,41) });

        var marker = L.marker( [locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {icon: icon});

        marker.bindPopup( locations[i][5] + " <br>" + locations[i][6] + " <br>" + locations[i][7] + " <br><br>" + locations[i][3] + " <br>" + locations[i][4] ).addTo( map );

        if(i == locations.length - 1){

            map.setView(new L.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 18);

            marker.bindPopup(locations[i][5] + " <br>" + locations[i][6] + " <br>" + locations[i][7] + " <br><br>" + locations[i][3] + " <br>" + locations[i][4]).openPopup().addTo( map );
        }

    } else {
        var icon2 = L.icon({iconUrl:"{{asset('assets/opmarkerblue1.png')}}", iconAnchor: new L.Point(0,32)});

        var marker = L.marker( [locations[i][1], locations[i][2]], {icon: icon2});

        marker.bindPopup( locations[i][5] + " <br>" + locations[i][6] + " <br>" + locations[i][7] + " <br><br>" + locations[i][3] + " <br>" + locations[i][4] ).addTo( map );
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`popupAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#icon-popupanchor) option when instantiating your `L.Icon`s. That's another `L.Point` with pixel coordinates *relative to the `iconAnchor`*.

The [tutorial for custom marker icons](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) also explains how the options for `L.Icon` work.